# Sending a query with a single transaction

Tags: mysql, r, r-dbi

I'm using the `DBI` package to send queries to a MySQL server.  I'd like to assure that these queries are sent as a single transaction in order to avoid table lock.

I use the `dbSendQuery` function to send queries:

```
df <- fetch(dbSendQuery(connection,
                  statement = "SELECT *
                               FROM table"),
      n = -1)
```

The DBI package says little about handling transactions, but what it does have is listed under these functions: `dbCommit`, `dbRollback` nor `dbCallProc` under the header:

> Note: The following methods deal with transactions and store
>   procedures.

in the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/DBI.pdf).  None seem to relate to sending queries as a single transaction.

How can I make sure I'm sending these queries as a single transaction?

Answer (score 2):

**Warning**: not tested.

You would need some help from MySQL. By default, MySQL runs with auto commit mode enabled. To disable auto commit mode, you would need to issue a `START TRANSACTION` statement. I suspect `dbCommit` and `dbRollback` simply execute `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`, respectively.

Details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

So you would need to do something like

```
dbSendQuery(connection, "START TRANSACTION")
# add your dbSendQuery code here
dbCommit(connection)
```